# n-Queens problem possible solutions by logical equivalences

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, applications, satisfiability

I'm studying Discrete maths recently, mainly through [MIT 6042J](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-spring-2015/) and [Rosen's Discrete Math and its applications](https://www.mheducation.com/highered/product/discrete-mathematics-applications-rosen/M9781259676512.html).

In the later, I found the following problem I can't figure out how to proceed:

The context is the well-known [n-Queens problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle) and on the textbook, the following compound preposition is given:

Let $p(i,j)$ be a proposition that is $True$ iff there's a queen in the $i$th row and $j$th column, where $i = 1...n$ and $j = 1...n$.

- to check all row contains at least one queen: $Q_1 = \land_{i=1}^n\lor_{j=1}^np(i,j)$
- to check at most one queen per row: $Q_2 = \land_{i=1}^n\land_{j=1}^{n-1}\land_{k=j+1}^n(\lnot p(i,j)\lor\lnot p(k,j))$

  - Here comes my first question. I believe it's wrong and should be $Q_2 = \land_{i=1}^n\land_{j=1}^{n-1}\land_{k=j+1}^n(\lnot p(i,j)\lor\lnot p(\textbf{i,k}))$ but I couldn't find any public errata. Does it make sense?
- to check at most one queen per column: $Q_3 = \land_{j=1}^n\land_{i=1}^{n-1}\land_{k=i+1}^n(\lnot p(i,j)\lor\lnot p(k,j))$
- to assert at most one queen on the diagonals:

  - $Q_4 = \land_{i=2}^n\land_{j=1}^{n-1}\land_{k=1}^{min(i-1,n-j)}(\lnot p(i,j)\lor\lnot p(i-k,k+j))$
  - $Q_5 = \land_{i=1}^{n-1}\land_{j=1}^{n-1}\land_{k=1}^{min(n-i,n-j)}(\lnot p(i,j)\lor\lnot p(i+k,j+k))$

So, to find valid results we need: $Q = Q_1 \land Q_2 \land Q_3 \land Q_4 \land Q_5$

I understand all of the proposed compound propositions and how they work. I could even easily convert them into an algorithm.

But the proposed exercises ask us to use them to find all the possible solutions for $n=4$. There are 65536 combinations for that, so, my second and final question is: is it possible to reduce these compounds with logic equivalences and, I'm not seeing it, or is it more probable that the book expects a computational solution for that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Regarding the second part of the question, did you check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Exercise_in_algorithm_design? Basically it suggest two very general improvement that are useful here: first, since there are a lot of symmetries and constraint, use them. Instead of $2^{4\times 4}$ you'll get something like $4^4$ by placing one queen per row. This will probably be enough (in fact 65536 is doable by a computer), but you can also use what's call *backtracking*. For the first part of your question, could you explain more in detail your formula. What's $p(i,j)$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did check the Wikipedia link and indeed the improvements are great, but the text course explicitly asks for using $Q$ for that so I'm not sure I could derive from $Q$ to some of these solutions using equivalences. But I'll check than deeper. 
About the second point, I'm very sorry about that, I totally forgot to mention what p means, I'll update the question with this information.

Comment: Even though with a $4^4$ solution it's kind of hard to do it manually, so I believe you suggest in both cases to use a computational solution for that. Yes, I do understand that 65536 is pretty doable to a computer, I just don't understand if that's what the text propose based on the question.

Comment: Try drawing, on a $4\times 4$ grid, if you consider the symmetries you only have 2 possible position for the first queen (A1:bottom or A2:first case above, the other positions are just mirrors). Then do the drawing and cross out every positions that are now forbidden by the queen. For A1 you have 2 possible positions (B3 and B4) for the second queen, for A2 only one). Continue crossing out the newly forbidden position and you'll see what's left (if I'm not mistaking, you'll end up with only one solution, hence two taking into account the mirror symmetry). This is sort of manual backtracking.

Comment: Based on your edit and the definition of $p(i,j)$, I agree that $1QueenperRow = \land_{r=1}^n\land_{c=1}^{n-1}\land_{c'=j+1}^n(\lnot \left( p(r,c) \wedge p(r,c') \right) =\land_{r=1}^n\land_{c=1}^{n-1}\land_{c'=j+1}^n(\lnot p(r,c) \vee \lnot p(r,c') $. 
 This would be coherent with $Q3 = 1QueenPerColumn$

Comment: To develop a bit what I'm saying in my previous comment, what you can do is some kind of backtracking/lazy evaluation: if you fix $p(1,1)=1$, then your formula will be false as soon as you put $p(1,.)=1$ or $p(.,1)=1$ or $p(i,i)=1, i>1$. So if you put $p(1,1)=1$, for column 2 you have to chose either $p(2,3)=1$ or (exclusive) $p(2,4)=1$, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input on the first question.
If I understand correctly your suggestion is that I could use $Q$ and instead of listing all the possibilities in a truth table I could do this lazy evaluation setting $p(1,1) = True$ and then remove a bunch of possibilities by just doing that. Makes sense, I will try to write down a solution with that and come back to you. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of testing all $4^{4\times 4}$ possibilities, you can do some backtracking/lazy evaluation.

Start by placing a queen in the first column, up to symetries there is only $2$ possible positions, $p(1,1)$ and $p(1,2)$, draw the two and start to explore the $p(1,1)$ branch.

This first queen induces a lot of constraints, we draw them in green and see that we have 2 possibilities for the placement of the second queen: $p(2,3)$ and $p(2,4)$. We draw these two configuration and carry on exploring the $p(1,1), p(2,3)$ branch.

Now, adding in red the constraints induced by the second queen and previously unconstrained, we see that there is no way to place a non-attacking queen in the third column, so we stop our exploration and go back to the next unexplored branch, $p(1,1),p(2,4)$.

Here we can put a non-attacking queen at $p(3,2)$ and carry on.

I won't describe the whole process, I think my drawing is way clearer.

[image: backtracking/lasy evalutation]

We end up with one suitable configuration $p(1,2),p(2,4),p(3,1), p(4,3)$, and we have to keep in mind that we used symmetry to simplify one half of the computations so $p(1,3),p(2,1),p(3,4),p(4,2)$ works as well.

Hence we have $2$ possibles configurations, this is coherent with http://oeis.org/A000170

I described the process manually, but it is also very suitable for computer programming. It also works in your logical framework, by doing the lazy evaluation of your $\wedge$ (which is $False$ as soon as one proposition is).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Comment: That's an amazing explanation/work, @thibo, thank you so much for that!